# chain transition of array in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I want to move a rectangle with given coordinates with d3.js. The x,y coordinate for transition is

> 1. [0,0]
> 2. [0,30]
> 3. [30,60]
> 4. [100,0]

So I coded

```js
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
    var coordinate=[
        [0,0],
        [0,30],
        [30,60],
        [100,0],          
        ];
    var square=svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x",coordinate[0][0])
      .attr("y",coordinate[0][1])
      .attr("width",60)
      .attr("height",60);
        
    square.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("x",coordinate[1][0])
        .attr("y",coordinate[1][1])
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("x",coordinate[2][0])
        .attr("y",coordinate[2][1])
        .transition()    
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("x",coordinate[3][0])
        .attr("y",coordinate[3][1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Okay, this work fine, but I have to write all the chain transitions by hand. And if the array gets larger... I don't wanna think about it.

What I want to do is applying transition function to first elements array, then to second element, to third, and so on.
I tried using for loop, but couldn't find good solutions.

Comment: Hello, did you check my answer? Is that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. I have used `forEach` method. You can use any looping functions like  `for` or `while`

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var coordinate = [
    [0,0],
    [0,30],
    [30,60],
    [100,0],          
];

var square = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x",coordinate[0][0])
  .attr("y",coordinate[0][1])
  .attr("width",60)
  .attr("height",60);

coordinate.forEach(function(d,i){ 
  if(i>0)
    square = square.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("x",d[0])
      .attr("y",d[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```